# How to bind a slider to a parameter so that the slider allows the choice between values in a data column?

Tags: user-interface, plot, slider, interactive, vega-lite

Suppose I have a column of data in Vega Lite, like `a` here, but larger: with 50 to 80 rows.

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "3.33"}, {"a": "3.36"}, {"a": "3.39"}, {"a": "3.42"}, {"a": "3.45"}, {"a": "3.48"},
      {"a": "3.51"}, {"a": "3.54"}, {"a": "3.57"}
    ]
  }
```

How to bind some parameter to a slider which would let the user interactively select which value from the column `a` should the parameter take?

I know that the following feature exists, but I would prefer not to use it because I already have the data in the column, and computing the range would be additional work:

```
{"input": "range", "min": 3.33,"max": 3.57,"step": 0.03}
```

Another reason that I want to avoid using a `range` is that (I think that) not all values would be accurately computed, because (I suppose that) Vega uses finite-precision floating point.

The following probably isn't relevant; but I'm using Vega Lite through the Julia VegaLite.jl interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you are using HTML and Javascript. Is that a possibility?

This code creates a Vega-Lite specification and binds a range slider in the HTML to the chart. The test property in the condition for color and size is used to compare the data value with the currently selected value. When the slider is moved, the selectedValue parameter is updated, and the chart reflects the changes.

We can use the data variable and extract the values array dynamically using the map() function. This way, you don't have to hardcode the values in the JavaScript code. Just update the data variable with your actual dataset, and the slider will work accordingly.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5.20.2"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@5.1.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6.18.2"></script>
<style>
#slider-container {
width: 250px;
position: relative;
}
.slider-label {
position: absolute;
bottom: -20px;
font-size: 11px;
font-family: "Arial"
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="vis"></div>
<div id="slider-container">
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" step="1" id="slider" style="width: 100%;" />
<div id="slider-labels"></div>
</div>
<script>
const data = [
{"a": "0.33"}, {"a": "0.36"}, {"a": "0.39"}, 
{"a": "1.33"}, {"a": "1.36"}, {"a": "1.39"}, 
{"a": "2.33"}, {"a": "2.36"}, {"a": "2.39"}, 
{"a": "3.33"}, {"a": "3.36"}, {"a": "3.39"}, 
{"a": "3.42"}, {"a": "3.45"}, {"a": "3.48"},
{"a": "3.51"}, {"a": "3.54"}, {"a": "3.57"},
{"a": "4.33"}, {"a": "4.36"}, {"a": "4.39"}
];

const spec = {
"$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
"data": {"values": data},
"width": 270,
"height": 60,
"mark": "circle",
"encoding": {
"x": {"field": "a", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"zero": false}},
"color": {
"condition": {"test": "datum.a === selectedValue", "value": "red"},
"value": "gray"
},
"size": {
"condition": {"test": "datum.a === selectedValue", "value": 100},
"value": 50
}
},
"params": [
{
"name": "selectedValue",
"value": data[0].a
}
]
};

const slider = document.getElementById('slider');
const sliderLabels = document.getElementById('slider-labels');
const values = data.map((d) => d.a);

function createSliderLabels() {
const labelCount = values.length;
const labelsToShow = 5; // Adjust this number to show more or fewer labels
const stepSize = Math.floor(labelCount / (labelsToShow - 1));

for (let i = 0; i < labelCount; i += stepSize) {
const label = document.createElement('div');
label.className = 'slider-label';
label.textContent = values[i];
label.style.left = `${(i / (labelCount - 1)) * 100}%`;
sliderLabels.appendChild(label);
}

// Ensure the last label is added
if (labelCount % stepSize !== 1) {
const label = document.createElement('div');
label.className = 'slider-label';
label.textContent = values[labelCount - 1];
label.style.left = '100%';
sliderLabels.appendChild(label);
}
}

vegaEmbed('#vis', spec).then((res) => {
slider.max = values.length - 1;
createSliderLabels();
slider.addEventListener('input', () => {
const selectedValue = values[slider.value];
res.view.signal('selectedValue', selectedValue).run();
});
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Adam